# Python Split Up A Dataframe Based On Its Row Index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Trying to break up a dataframe into train, val, and test dataframes based on its row index e.g. observation 1 will go into training, 2 into val, and 3 into test, however, I'm hitting a roadblock. Here's my code thus far:

```
climbingTngDataset = pd.DataFrame([])
climbingValDataset = pd.DataFrame([])
climbingTestDataset = pd.DataFrame([])

for i in range(len(dfClimbing)):
    if i % 2 == 0:
       climbingValDataset.append(i) 
    if i % 3 == 0:
        climbingTestDataset.append(i)
    else:
        climbingTngDataset.append(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `groupby` to split your dataFrame:

```
train, test, val = [
    g for _, g in dfClimbing.groupby(dfClimbing.index % 3)
]
```

---

**Demo**
(With two splits instead of 3)

```
print(df)
   Record ID Para Tag
0          1    A   x
1          1    A   y
2          2    B   x
3          2    B   y
4          1    A   z

i, j = [g for _, g in df.groupby(df.index % 2)]

print(i)
   Record ID Para Tag
0          1    A   x
2          2    B   x
4          1    A   z

print(j)
   Record ID Para Tag
1          1    A   y
3          2    B   y
```